# What counts as a walled zone in Towns?

Tags: towns

I have heard that a zone which is completely surrounded by walls (with doors and windows permitted) results in more efficient production.

Does this require that the zone **have a room to itself** (i.e. all floor tiles within the wall are that zone) or merely that **the zone is within a room** (so that multiple zones can share one room/building)?

Or is it simply that zones are enhanced by nearby walls, without regard to whether they are contiguous?

Additionally, does it matter whether the walls are more than 1 block high (i.e. cannot be walked over), or whether there is a roof?

Comment: The [utilities](http://www.townswiki.com/wiki/Utilities) wiki entry suggests you definitely need the roof, but I can't see anything about whether the zone needs a room to itself or just needs to be in an area flagged as 'enclosed by walls on all sides'. I can't check while at work, so this comment'll have to do until I can check and write up a full answer.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it just needs to be inside, that is, under a roof. This is actually what led to me changing from building below ground to building above ground.

Comment: Source? Experimental data?

Comment: I read it a while back, long enough that I don't remember where. Somewhere that I considered a trustworthy source. This *was* before the changes to roofs, though, so I suppose something may have changed. The wiki supports my answer.

Comment: @SaintWacko If the wiki supports your answer can you include a source link?